# Iqueryable as a subquery to filter another iqueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

I have a many to many relationship (Sites, Categories, CategoriesXSite) and two iqueryable defined variables like this:

```
IQueryable<Site> sitesQuery = from s in db.Sites
                         where s.Name.Contains(siteWord)
                         select s



IQueryable<SiteCategorie> categoriesQuery = from c in db.SiteCategories
                                       where c.Parent.ID == 1
                                       select c;
```

I want to be able to apply a filter to categories iqueryable based on sites iqueryable so that way I can have any categories with any filters plus another filter of the categories that has sites containing certain filter, some thing like this:

```
from c in categoriesQuery 
where c.Sites == sitesQuery
select c
```

I've made a similar question before when I didn't need to filter categories as well ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454227/using-pre-existing-iqueryable-to-filter-another-iqueryable-on-entity-framework))

Thanks a lot,

Comment: "I'm a software lover and a fan of best practices" - best practice is to accept those answers that you find best respond to your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll probably want either

```
from c in categoriesQuery  
where c.Sites.Any(s => sitesQuery.Contains(s))
select c
```

or

```
from c in categoriesQuery  
where c.Sites.All(s => sitesQuery.Contains(s))
select c
```

depending on your use case.

Comment: Nice simple and working solution. Thanks alot - works like a charm!